# Convert curl to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, curl

I need to translate this curl request to AJAX format `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/xml' --header 'Authorization: Basic eGZlZG9yMDNAc3R1ZC5maXQudnV0YnIuY3o6YXVkZWxpdmVy' 'http://example.com/user'`

I made

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "http://example.com/user",
dataType: "xml",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic eGZlZG9yMDNAc3R1ZC5maXQudnV0YnIuY3o6YXVkZWxpdmVy");
},   
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
  alert(xhr.status);      
  alert(thrownError);
}
})
```

This request returns "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/user. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.". 
Can somebody advise me on this ?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)` issue.  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: I don't think this would be CORS as it's 404. Ensure that you can access that URL via xhr before attempting the login though..

Also, make sure that Authorization header is properly formatted as it is in the CURL req

Comment: it "works" without authorization, it's returning XML object with 401, with authorization it throws only this error

Comment: @JakubFedor Add the accept header, and double check your authorization header, at a glance it looks like it could be incorrect

Comment: @user2879041 so I added everything and I've got still the same error damn

Comment: @JakubFedor Make the request via CURL like you have been (hopefully it's still successful) and take a screen shot of the request in a network debugger with all the headers/params etc.

Do the same thing with AJAX, take a screenshot of the request + headers and post them online, I'd take a look for you

And do the same with the responses

Comment: Also, like @cmorrissey said it actually could be CORS failing, I don't know why it would give a 404 though, seems strange. Basically, if you're making the request across domains you will have to have the Origin: <your domain> in the request and the response from example.com would have to have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <yourdomain> and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Comment: @JakubFedor it would be easier if you could post a screen shot, and also send the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but this doesn't work in pure javascript code (meaning something like running script.js) but it works in chrome extensions, when you put server you are trying to connect in permissions.